# Typescript - Read and return all query parameter values that matches a specific parameter

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, url-parameters, react-typescript

From an url, I want to get all query parameter values that matches a specific parameter.

For instance, if we have a string such as

`?code1=AF&code1=AE&code1=GE&code3=FW`

Is it possible to query the string for all values relating to parameter `code1`?

For example, the above would return a list such as `[AF,AE,FW]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) for this use case:

```js
const parameters = new URLSearchParams('?code1=AF&code1=AE&code1=GE&code3=FW');
const result = parameters.getAll('code1'); // ["AF", "AE", "FW"]
```

Comment: no problem - feel free to accept the answer if it answered your question